# Is there a way to make eclipse identify a change to classes in another maven project when I save that class?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

An example, to make it clear:

I have a maven project containing interfaces, for example, UserServiceInterf.

The other project contains the implementation of that interface, UserServiceImpl.

I add a method to UserServiceInterf, which I intend to override in UserServiceImpl. What I have to do for eclipse to identify this change is to mvn install the Interf project and refresh the Impl project. Reinstalling the project every time I add a method to an interface is really annoying.

For reference, testing the same on Netbeans, it refreshes instantly, no need to install or F5 the project. Problem is that our team already uses and prefer Eclipse, so, if there's a solution for Eclipse, I'd appreciate.

Comment: Using Eclipse Luna (4.4), I have both projects (multiple projects in fact) imported as Maven projects in my (single) workspace, with auto-build, and changes *do* get propagated without `maven install`. There must be something different in your setup.

Comment: I'm using Neon, but I'll test in Mars and Luna. Maybe one info I missed is that they are not modules, just jar projects being added as dependency.

Comment: If you right-click the "Impl" project and choose "Configure Build Path" > "Libraries" tab and expand "Maven Dependencies", do you see the interface dependency as a project (with folder icon) or just as ordinary jar? I see a project dependency there.

Comment: I see it as a project folder too.

Comment: Tested in Luna and Mars too, didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project which contains the implementations, go to `Maven -> Enable/Disable Workspace Resolution`. If it is enabled, it will then reference the other project which is imported, and changes will reflect immediately, without needing to do a `mvn install` on the other project.

This is provided by m2e-wtp plugin which is installed by default in latest Eclipse versions.

Comment: I never noticed it, but it was enabled. Tried to disable and re-enable, didn't work. Well, at least I know it's something wrong in here.

Comment: Hmm...that's strange. Also make sure that the version of the project you're referencing in pom.xml is the same as the project imported into Eclipse.

Comment: @GuilhermeOrioli Go to the implementation class and press SHIFT and then click on the `UserServiceInterf` name. Where does it take you to? It should take you to the UserServiceInterf.java file in the interfaces project.

Comment: I believe by SHIFT you mean CTRL. It takes me to .class, regardless of "Workspace Resolution" being enabled. Pretty sure that's the problem.